# How to serialize related models in Django Rest API?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, rest, django-rest-framework

I have tried all the solutions. Still cannot resolve it. Here are the codes.

***models.py***

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    car_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_name + ' - ' + str(self.pk)

class Owners(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner_desc = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('appname:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner_name + ' - ' +    self.owner_desc
```

***serializers.py***

```
class OwnersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Owners
        fields = '__all__'


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  

    owners = OwnersSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'
```

***views.py***

```
class CarList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        cars = Car.objects.all()
        serializer = CarSerializer(cars, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

I can't get to view all the 'Owner' objects related to a certain object of the 'Car' class.

Comment: What does the output serialized data look like?  And what do you want it to look like?

Comment: You're not getting the description field either.  Have you tried setting the `fields` value explicitly to include all the fields, instead of just using `__all__`

Comment: Oops, I got the description data. Edited.  
  [
    {
        "car_name": "ada",
        "car_description": "adad"
    },
    {
        "car_name": "sdada",
        "car_description": "fafa"
    }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a related name on the ForeignKey to create the reverse reference.

```
class Owners(models.Model):

    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, related_name='owners')
```